# Vertical scrollbar with a dojo OnDemandGrid

Tags: dojo, usability, dgrid

Is it possible to add a vertical scrollbar to an [OnDemandGrid](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/OnDemandList-and-OnDemandGrid)?

Yes, I realize that an OnDemandGrid lets you scroll through a million records, and it will be awkward to imagine a scrollbar that lets you scroll all the way up and down through those million records, but I'd say it'll be good if there was a way to add a scrollbar at least to scroll through a reasonable subset around the visible viewport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind my question - I realized that it was actually showing the vertical scrollbar by default all this while, but it was hidden off the right of the page due to a large width on the div containing the dgrid.